# Correct way to join user table to content table?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

So I have two tables.

One storing users, named `user`:

```
id     date_joined      username
1      2014-12-12       UserA
2      2014-11-11       UserB
```

And another storing content, named `article`:

```
id     user_id      date           content
1      1            2014-10-10     content here
2      1            2014-11-10     content here
3      2            2014-12-10     content here
4      1            2014-13-10     content here
```

What is the correct way to query this data to get the username for each user alongside the content?

I have this currently:

```
SELECT user.username, article.date, article.content
FROM article
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = article.user_id
ORDER BY article.date
```

Which works, but is a complete guess. Is this the correct query? Do I need the `user.` and `article.` in all elements? Or just for the `LEFT JOIN` bit?

So is this also correct/recommended?

```
SELECT username, date, content
FROM article
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = article.user_id
ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the *table.column* syntax only on cases that there's a column with the same name on both. if there's only one option- no need (although in my mind makes the query clearer)

as for the query itself- it's good, but one thing you need to know (and decide what you want, not clear from your question) - left join or inner join.
inner join - will give you only results which exist in both tables (i.e. - if user_id 3 exists on article and not on user - you wont get it. with left join - in such case you'll get user_id 3 record, with the values from article table, and nulls on the user table columns
so it depends on the need to decide which, but basically your query is fine

Answer (score 0):

I like using aliases for the table names.  I think it makes it easier to read.  With RIGHT JOIN it will return everything from the right table (article) that is also present in the right table (article).

```
SELECT u.username, a.date, a.content
FROM article AS a
RIGHT JOIN user AS u
ON u.id = a.user_id
ORDER BY a.date
```

LEFT JOIN will only produce the matches on id that are in the left table (user)